# How do I style numbers?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to change the styling of numbers.

- I want to add some space between every 3 digits.
- I will know exactly where the numbers will be located in the html.
- When I retrieve the number from the html it needs to be the exact same number as I entered. So I **only want to style the number**, not modify the number.
- I may use javascript and/or css to try an achieve this

```js
//test for success . . . do not remove
if(document.getElementById('number').innerHTML !== "1000"){
  alert('Wrong answer, you changed the number!!!');
}
```

```html
<p id="number">1000<p>

<p>The 1000 above should show up like 1 000<p>
```

Comment: Put the original value in a data-attribute and read that back, then you can make it look like whatever you like?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=JavaScript+number+formatting+library

Comment: The libraries and and data-attributes may be nice workarounds. But I would prefer it if I wouldn't have to use them.

Comment: why not using span and put each 3 digit inside span and add some margin. The innerHtml will change but the innerText no

Comment: @kiranvj Someone called kiranvj actually showed that with `p::first-letter` I would be able to style the first letter with padding. Unfortunately he removed the answer after some feedback that  `p::nth()-letter` doesn't exist. Maybe we will be able to select a letter in the string and apply a padding to it somehow?

Comment: so you would need to parse the innerHTML/texr, match the numbers and set the text

Comment: @Temani Afif  That might actually work. It shouldn't be too hard to insert the spans on the right places with javascript. Changing the check in the question to innerText would be acceptable I suppose.

Comment: @kiranvj was faster than me ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```js
const numberWithSep = (x) => {
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "<div class='sep'></div>");
}

var num = numberWithSep('12345678');


document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = num;

//retrive like this
console.log(document.getElementById("number").innerText);
```

```css
.sep {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p id="number"><p>
```

If you want the separator as comma (,) just change the `div` to `,`

Comment: This looks pretty good. Is there a reason you are placing them in a `div` and not a `span` by the way? PS: Guess I'll (re)read up a bit on regular expressions ;).

Comment: @RMo `span` is an inline element so we cannot apply padding without setting display property. In our case since we are setting `display: inline-block` we can change div with span.

Comment: heh I couldn't resist duck-duck-go-ing that. I was pretty sure I had seen paddings applied to inline spans. I actually found this document claiming inline elemens are biderectional: https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/box.html#bidi-box-model. It basically states that `padding-left` and `padding-right` are valid properties in an inline element, but `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` aren't. In rtl or ltr directions at least.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `display:flex` so that the "sep" character is in auto-determined `font-size`.

The idea is that turn `<p>1000</p>` into `<p><span>1</span><span>0</span><span>0</span><span>0</span></p>` by js.

Then, add "sep" character visually by css generated content. `span:nth-last-of-type(3n) { content:<sep>; ..}`. This way, the `<sep>`(can be any character actually) will have same font-size as number text.

[demo](https://codepen.io/ycw7788/pen/JOzmBR)

Comment: I can't get this through the test successfully. There are also issues as soon as I use a floating-point number instead of an integer. By the way when did css variables become a thing? I complete missed it xD.

Comment: @RMo demo updated. now handle float num and eliminated all custom props.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple and easy:

```
const numberFormat = (x) => {
  return x.replace(/(.{4})/g, "$1 ");
}
```